# python - reporting key with highest value, or tie

Tags: python

I know this is really simple, and it's probably already been answered somewhere, but I'm having lots of trouble finding it anywhere, probably because I'm searching for the wrong term.

I have something like this (but far more complicated):

```
score = {}
z = 4
while z > 0:
    score[z] = random.randrange(1,12)
    z -= 1
```

So eventually I arrive at these values:

```
score[1] = 7
score[2] = 9
score[3] = 12
score[4] = 7
```

I want something to set a variable to 3, because score[3] is the largest.

```
score[1] = 9
score[2] = 9
score[3] = 7
score[4] = 8
```

And in this instance, it should set the variable to 0 or something, because the highest number is a tie.

Comment: Are you intending score to be a dictionary ("{}") or a List ("[]")?

Comment: @CptSupermrkt that assignment would not work from an empty list and the OP never mentions lists.

Comment: I know, that's why I'm trying to figure out what he's trying to do because there are contradictions in his question.

Comment: I believe I want score to be a dictionary, because I'm modifying it elsewhere with while loops, changing the key.

Comment: @CptSupermrkt what contradictions? They said "key", used dictionary syntax, ...

Comment: @user3750369 If your keys are actually useful descriptors (e.g. `{"Adam":255, "Steve":12,"Jeremy":160}`) then I agree with using a dictionary. If they're not, then lists are a better fit here and you should refactor the rest of your code to fit.

Comment: @jonsharpe Yeah you're right.  I work all day with dictionary keys that are meaningful strings so when I saw [1] I mistakenly saw them as numerical indexes (i.e. a List).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

score=Counter()
score[1] = 7
score[2] = 9
score[3] = 12
score[4] = 7
print score
Counter({3: 12, 2: 9, 1: 7, 4: 7})
print score.most_common()[0][1],score.most_common()[1][1]
12 9
```

If `score.most_common()[0][1] == score.most_common()[1][1]` there are two equal max values so set variable to 0

`else set variable to score.most_common()[0][0]`  which is the key of the highest  value

```
score=Counter()
score[1] = 9
score[2] = 9
score[3] = 7
score[4] = 8
print score
print score.most_common()[0][1],score.most_common()[1][1]
print score.most_common()[0][1]==score.most_common()[1][1]
Counter({1: 9, 2: 9, 4: 8, 3: 7})
9 9
True
```

Comment: Reread the question more carefully and realized this one gets closest to what the author intended. Excellent use of `Counter`!

Comment: Thanks, yes the only values that matter are the first two highest so most_common comes in handy.

Comment: This is a totally non-intuitive use of `Counter`. You're lucky that the values were integers!

Answer (score 5):

```
max_score = max(score.values())
keys = [k for k in score if score[k] == max_score]
```

This produces a list of the keys that have the highest score, whether that's one or more.

Comment: This is technically correct (and very elegant, mind you) but don't you think it's a bit silly that OP is working with a dictionary to begin with? Are we supposed to infer that his keys will be something other than fancy list indexes?

Comment: @AdamSmith I don't judge, I just assume the OP has their reasons. Maybe that's naive of me in this case since the example uses incrementing integers.

Comment: I normally don't either when the OP's code makes sense, however in this case I'm given to believe he's a novice programmer that could use a bit more direction. Your answer, although correct, provides little of that. You've still earned my +1, however, for tackling the problem in the most straightforward way.

Answer (score 2):

If you must use a dictionary for `score`, then you can use the functional form:

```
def index_of_highest_score(scores):
    max_score = max(scores.values())
    keys = []
    for key, value in scores.iteritems():
        if value == max_score:
            keys.append(key)
    if len(keys) > 1:
        return 0
    else:
        return keys[0]

score = {}
score[1] = 7
score[2] = 9
score[3] = 12
score[4] = 7
print index_of_highest_score(score) # Prints 3

score[1] = 9
score[2] = 9
score[3] = 7
score[4] = 8
print index_of_highest_score(score) # Prints 0
```

Comment: Dictionaries don't have indices.

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted. Using a list and its `.index` method is the most Pythonic solution here.

Comment: I assumed `score` was a `list` at first. Saw your comment then checked the question and hit the panic button. Thanks for the heads up! I've edited my answer to deal with both cases.